# How do I correctly declare my if or while statement to meet the desired input?

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop

Okay so I am still way of a beginner at c++.
I have been attempting to code a decent basic calculator in order to test my basics and what I know.
I can not for the life of me understand why the program does not restart through loop and just continues to end every time, whether I input "Yes", "yes", "Y", or "y". Here is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    string c, d;

    while(c != "+", "-", "*", "/" or c == "Yes", "yes", "Y", "y") {

    cout << "N1 = ";    cin >> a;   cout << endl;
    if(!cin)//If anything but integer given, program ends
    {
        cout << "Give a Number next time.. " << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "N2 = ";    cin >> b;   cout << endl;
    if(!cin)
    {
        cout << "Give a Number next time.. " << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    cout << "+ , - , * or / ? ";   cin >> c;   cout << endl;
    if(!cin)
    {
        cout << "Give a Number next time.. " << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    if( c == "+")//Operator Functions from input
    {
        cout << a + b << endl;
    }
    else if( c == "-")
    {
        cout << a - b << endl;
    }
    else if( c == "*")
    {
        cout << a * b << endl;
    }
    else if( c == "/")
    {
        cout << a / b << endl;
    }

    if(c != "+ , -, * , /")//if not operator, Try again?
    {
        cout << "Again?... Y/N? " << endl;
        cin >> c;
    }

    if(c == "Yes", "yes", "Y", "y")
    {
        cout << "Restarting.. " << endl;
    }

    while(c == "No", "no", "N", "n")
    {
        cout << "closing... " << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I have also tried changing the very last `while` to an `if` statement but neither works. Just hoping to see what I am misunderstanding. Thanks!
Maybe even some tips to shorten my code or make it simpler would be much obliged as well!

Comment: `if(c != "+ , -, * , /")` You can't "chain" comparisons like this, this just compares `c` to the string `"+ , -, * , /"`. You'll need to spell it out for the compiler: `if(c != "+" &&  c != "-" && c != "*" &&  c != "/")`, same for further below.

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` when flushing the output isn't necessary. `'\n'` works just fine for starting a new line.

Comment: Thanks user657267! Thanks as well pete, I knew about '\n' but what exactly does it mean to flush the output and in what case would I use std:endl?

Comment: @Jack Output is normally buffered - what you output is written into a buffer in memory and is only sent to the actual device (terminal, file, whatever) when the stream is flushed. Flush happens when the stream closes, when the buffer grows beyond a certain size, or when `std::flush` or `std::endl` is used on the stream. Since flushing is usually a slow operation, it makes sense not to do it needlessly. Which also means not using `std::endl` as simply a line terminator - that's what `'\n'` is for.

Answer (score 3):

The comma operator `,` does not do what you think it does. Its semantics is: "Evaluate the left-hand side, discard the value, evaluate the right-hand side and use that as the result of the expression." It also has the lowest precedence. The `if` condition is therefore parsed like this:

```
if ( ((((c == "Yes"), "yes"), "Y"), "y") )
```

So the evaluated value of the conidition is `"y"`. This undergoes the array-to-pointer conversion followed by a pointer-to-bool conversion, and since the pointer is non-null, it evaluated to `true`.

The correct way to spell the condition would be:

```
if (c == "Yes" || c == "yes" || c == "Y" || c == "y")
```

using the logical OR operator `||`. The same applies to the `while` condition as well, of course.

And it the first `if` condition (the one with `!=`), you're testing whether the string is different from a literal string `+ , -, * , /`, which it most certainly will. It seems you intended this:

```
if (c != "+" && c != "-" && c != "*" && c != "/")
```

That is, enter the conditional `c` is not `+` AND it's not `-` AND it's not `*` AND it's not `/`.

---

As per your comments, if you find repeating the comparison tedious, you could wrap it in a function:

```
bool isOneOf(const std::string &needle, std::initializer_list<std::string> haystack)
{
  return std::find(begin(haystack), end(haystack), needle) != end(haystack);
}
```

The conditional would then be spelled like this:

```
if (isOneOf(c, {"Yes", "yes", "Y", "y"}))
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b937e0cb3a03a51)

Comment: So would it be correct to assume after each logical operator the computer reads it as a separate entity no matter which logical operator I use in the if or even while statements?

Comment: @Jack I'm sorry, I cannot understand what you want to say with your comment; can you re-phrase it, plase? What is the "it" that the computer "reads," and what exactly do you mean with "reads" here?

Comment: For instance `if (c == "Yes" || c == "yes" || c == "Y" || c == "y")` Each one `c == "yes"` would be read from the computer as a separate entity. Meaning each time it looks at `c == "Yes"` once the `||` `or` operator is used, the next value `c == "yes"` or `c == "Y"` would have to include the `c ==`. There is no way to shorten this?

Comment: @Jack Yes, that's how expressions normally work in C++, and it helps readability. However, I have added a potential shortening to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of points,

1. Rather than using `if-elseif-elseif-else` for +, -, *, / cases, you can use `switch` instead:

   ```
   switch(c) {
   case '+':
       //do something
       break;
   case '-':
       //do something
       break;
   }
   ```

   This is because you actually only use `c` instead of having some other conditions, thus switch may be more suitable. `if-else` is better suited for something like:

   ```
   if (c == 'a'){
     ....
   } else if (b == 36) { //notice there is a different variable used here
    ....
   }
   ```

   Edit: as pointed out in the comment, this requires `c` to be changed to `char`. This way is cleaner, but you need different variable for `string` which accepts "Yes", "yes", "Y", "y", etc... inputs.
2. In your last case for "Restarting/Closing", the while loop is not necessary

Comment: @Angew You are right. I just noticed that c is `string` in the OP definition. This is because I instinctively consider `c` as `char`. I edited my answer

Answer (score -1):

Building on top of Angew's excellent answer It is often easier when you have so many options to move the qualifier to a separate function that contains a switch statement with complete fall through. This would dramatically improve the readability of your code, and is particularly useful if you want to reuse the same statements elsewhere. Such an example is shown below. Keep in mind that this is just a suggestion and does not apply in all situations. Using a switch statement could also dramatically improve the rest of your code instead of using extensively long `else if()` statements.

Replace this:

```
while(c != "+", "-", "*", "/" or c == "Yes", "yes", "Y", "y")
```

With this:

```
while(ValidateOperatorInput(input_string)) // c in your case.
```

And include this function somewhere in your code:

```
inline bool ValidateOperatorInput(const std::string &input) {
    switch(input) {
        case "+": case"-": case "*": case "/": 
        case "Yes": case "yes": case "Y": case "y":
        return true;
        break;
        // If the input string is not equal to any of the above cases then
        // return false.
        default:
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::string` is not an ordinal type and so cannot be used in a `switch`.

Comment: @Angew You are right of course, I just used this the other day in java and thought it would be transferable. I apologies for my ignorance.